# Destroying 1 of 2 GameObjects with that same script attached in UNITY

Tags: unity, c#

So I have 2 GameObjects, and they have exactly the same script attached to them called 'RoomSpawner'. Via this script, I want to destroy just ONE of these TWO GameObjects. How can I do this? By typing Destroy(gameObject); It will destroy 2 GameObjects :/, I'm confused, any ideas?

Those 2 GameObjects are in the same positions, and I want to delete them by OnTriggerEnter2D

Comment: Ok, but *which one* do you want to destroy? If you can explain to me how to make that distinction, then you can write that distinction into code.

Comment: Did you try implementing singleton pattern. So you won't have 2 of them in first place. Like have a static Instance of itself on Start if null, else delete itself. Then whenever a second one will be created it will commit suicide automatically. )))

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple. Have the one you don't wanna destroy with a public bool and check it true in the inspector:

```
//other variables...
public bool doNotDestroy;
//other code...
function OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
{
  //other statments...
  if (collision.gameObject.name = /*name of needed object to hit*/  && doNotDestroy == false)
{
  //destroy code...
}
}
//rest of code follows...
```

Comments indicate places where the rest of your script would be.

Comment: Yea, that would work.. BUT due to my project (procedural dungeon generator) I have to randomly delete ONE of the 2 GameObjects, no matter which one. Im coonfused, I've tried whole night :D

Comment: @SewerynPokutycki Please add the fact that it's random to your question

Comment: @SewerynPokutycki yes that would be helpful to others: to edit in the fact these objects are generated run-time

Comment: I think @The_Mattbat999 got the answer if you got 2 classes, on collision you can get the other.collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Classname> change the boolean that go in collision. Now you can prevent that script been execute on collision.

Answer (score -1):

I can put my head through,  ok
Create An empty gameObject and make your GameObjects Childrens of the former, 
Add the script and create a private List of gameObjects, 
Set it in the Start,
Use foreach statement to get the component GameObject,
Instead of Destroy,  SetActive the gameObject at the index to False. 
I think that will do.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question of how to destroy one and only one of the objects via OnTriggerEnter2D.

Answer (score -2):

Okay So I found out solution, I've simple checked GameObject's ID and destroy them.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer! Don't forget to come back in a couple of days to mark it as the accepted one!

Comment: @Seweryn can you elaborate on how you did this?

Answer (score -2):

Super simple solution use static variables

Comment: Exactly how would you recommend applying static variables to solve this problem?